# Force explorer to reload registry value

Tags: c++, windows, registry, explorer

I am trying to write a little code in c++ that hide my C drive.

I have read this link:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938267.aspx

and its work just fine if I restart "explorer.exe" process.

I am looking for another way to force explorer to reload his registry values and hide my device without restart explorer.

I have tried to use `RegFlushKey()` function, but it does not work for me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Does just hitting F5 work?

If not you could try the below:

> Broadcasting a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message.  For example:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam, uint fuFlags, uint uTimeout, IntPtr lpdwResult);

    private static readonly IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffff);
    private const int WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1a;
    private const int SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x0002;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, null, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 100, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

[from this MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/ce540c7d-a113-4f39-956e-0af6bc91abd3/force-updaterefresh-of-windows-start-menu)

Or this (there is a chance it will not restart explorer -- it could just cause it to refresh):

```
wmic process where name="explorer.exe" call terminate
```

Comment: I already tried this:

`SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, (LPARM)"Policy", SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 100, IntPtr.Zero);`

and it didn't work for me.

I have tried also to use: 

`SHChangeNotify(SHNCE_UPDATEITEM, SHCNF_IDLIST,NULL,NULL)`

But this also dont work for me. 

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try this command:

Comment: `wmic process where name="explorer.exe" call terminate`

Comment: this will terminate my explorer, and I don't wanna do that. my goal is refresh the explorer setting from the registry without any change to the front-end user. (something like F5 if it was work)